# Notation in Double Dual Mapping

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

I am quite confused at the notation used for $J$ in the following question:

> For a normed space $\Omega$, let $\Omega^{**}$ denote the dual space of the dual space. Let $J: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega^{**}$ be defined by $\langle x^*, J(x)\rangle   =  \langle x, x^*\rangle  = x^*(x)$. Show that $J$ is a linear isometry.

Where, for $x^* \in \Omega$, $\langle x, x^*\rangle = x^*(x)$.

I am confused on how to decipher the notation for $J$. I am normally use to things like $J(x) = $ fill in the blank. Could someone please explain this notation?

Comment: If $x\in \Omega$, then $J(x)\in \Omega^{**}$ so it is a functional on $\Omega^*$, and thus you have to plug in an element $x^* \in \Omega^*$. The definition should be $J(x)(x^*):=...$, but you can also denote this pairing as $<x^*, J(x) >$.

Comment: If you write the function application as $f(y)$, the definition becomes $(J(x))(x^{\ast}) = x^{\ast}(x)$. Or $J(x) \colon x^{\ast} \mapsto x^{\ast}(x)$. Verbally, $J(x)$ is evaluation at $x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So, this is just the evaluation map, as in linear algebra?

Comment: Yes. Only in linear algebra one doesn't consider continuity, so this is the restriction of the evaluation map to continuous linear forms. And it needs to be shown (though it's easy) that $J(x) \colon \Omega^{\ast} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous.

Comment: Hint: Riesz representation theorem for linear functionals.  I'm typing a full answer below if you'd like to just read the proof.

Comment: @D_S Well, I answered the question. But, no one has answered it officially.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought you had still had a question about surjectivity

Comment: @D_S I did, but then I figured it out. This question does need to be answered, though. Answer, so I can give points!

Comment: Haha, thank you for the offer :)